# What is the difference between bachelor's, master's and PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, undergraduate

What's the basic difference between these degrees? Who might choose one versus the other?

Comment: your title does not match your question. Did  mean `masters` for `undergraduate ` in your question?

Comment: What type of masters?  Master by research -- demonstrate that you know how to conduct research.  PhD -- know to do research + new contributions.

Answer (score 3):

A bachelor's or a master's is for practitioners.  A PhD is for researchers.  For example, if you're studying computer science and your goal is a software development job at Google or Facebook, a master's would be a great choice.  But if you'd like to join their research groups or become tenure track faculty at an [R1 university](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_I_university), you probably need a PhD.